# How do I get ClientID of custom control in asp.net 2.0?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, custom-controls, asp.net-2.0

I'm using ASP.NET 2.0 and am having difficulty obtaining the correct clientId of a custom control.   The clientId returned is not the same id that is being rendered in the HTML.

The rendered id in the HTML is

> _ctl0_cphMain_theControl_MyControl

But the clientID returned from asp.net is this. Notice how the _MyControl is missing?

> _ctl0_cphMain_theControl

This is the code I'm using to get clientId on the aspx page that is used in javascript.   This code directly on the aspx page, it is not generated from the code behind file.

```
document.getElementById('<%= theControl.ClientID %>')
```

The custom control is basically a text box.  It overrides the CreateChildControls() method and in that method, it sets the id of the text box to "MyControl".

I'm sure I'm trying to do something during the wrong time during the page life cycle or something.  I just don't know how to get the correct clientId in my javascript?

Comment: you can try using Jquery to get the control, it has selectors which can find the control based on how it starts or end, so doesn't have to match exactly.  so if you know the control always ends with _MyControl you can use Jquery to locate controls which end with that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I've never used JQuery before, so I'll have to play around with it.